# OpenMP - Variable declarations in for loops

Tags: variables, openmp

I'm trying to adapt a normal code to a parallel one. When I make a for loop parallel, which has some variables declared inside of it, are those variables private or shared?

Should I define each of them as private when I define the pragma?

---

By the way, one last question. I can use for-pragma with an initial parameter of an iterator too right? like `for(iter=xlist.begin() ; ... )`

I use latest version of codeblocks and mingw.

Answer (score 9):

Anything declared inside a parallel region (whether it's a loop or not) is private, with exceptions as listed below in @ejd 's comment.  You can't list it as private on the `#pragma` line as the variable doesn't exist yet.

So for instance in the below, even with `default(none)` we don't need to specify the sharing of `tid` even if you could; it's inside the parallel section, so it is private to each thread.   (Note too that you don't really need to specify i as private, as the loop index of an omp for is necessarily private.)

```
$ more foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(i)
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Thread %d gets iteration %d\n", tid, i);
    }

    return 0;
}
gpc-f103n084-$ !g
gcc -o foo foo.c -fopenmp 
$ ./foo
Thread 1 gets iteration 2
Thread 1 gets iteration 3
Thread 3 gets iteration 6
Thread 3 gets iteration 7
Thread 0 gets iteration 0
Thread 0 gets iteration 1
Thread 4 gets iteration 8
Thread 4 gets iteration 9
Thread 2 gets iteration 4
Thread 2 gets iteration 5
```

Comment: Yeah but I thought maybe I should declare them before the definition of the pragma and use them afterwards. I suspected of a possible illegal use since I've never seen such an example in the tutorials that I've read.

Comment: No, actually, having them defined inside the parallel section is good, it makes things much clearer.  Anything that is local to a particular loop index is necessarily something that can usefully made private to the corresponding thread.

Comment: much thanks, it has really been a great help. thank u so much

Comment: By the way, one last question. I can use for pragma with an initial parameter of an iterator too right? like for(iter=xlist.begin() ; ... )

Comment: Jonathan - your statement "anything declared inside a parallel section (whether it's a loop or not) is private" isn't totally accurate.  The OpenMP specification clearly lists what is and isn't private by default.  For example, static variables declared inside the construct are shared, as are variables with heap allocated storage, and (in V3.0) variables with const-qualified type having no mutable members are shared.  There are specific default rules for whether these variables are declared within a construct or a region (the term "parallel section" doesn't have a meaning in this regard).

Comment: I wouldn't normally feel bad about leaving out some special cases, but the way I said it so flatly is definitely misleading.  I'll update the answer to point to your comment.

Comment: Jonathan - I understand, but I have found that making blanket statements when you don't have the user's code in front of you is "dangerous".  Just because you think that something is unlikely usually means that is what they did and just didn't describe the problem well enough.  Just my 2 cents worth.

Answer (score 4):

If you need them only within the loop block and you want to parallelize the loop, leave them inside the loop block. If you declare them outside of the parallel construct and declare them as private, each thread will have its own copy. So it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you so much. By the way, one last question. I can use for-pragma with an initial parameter of an iterator too right? like "for(iter=xlist.begin() ; ... )"

Comment: This depends on the OpenMP specification your compiler supports. I think you can use the for pragma for iterators with OpenMP 3.0.